# How to Return an Array from Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

Hi i have a function which should return Array, in the below function,  `this.cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(this.cordovaFile.dataDirectory, storageId)` actually returns an Promise Array which  i am converting it into Observable and storing into `timesheetArray` variable and Now  `timesheetArray` it will return Observable array but i just want to return just a Array. Below is the code

Please help, If it return just an array i dont need to change it anywhere , because this function is used through out the application

```
public getAllTimesheets(): TimesheetModel[] {
  const storageId = TIMESHEET_KEYS.ALL_TIMESHEET;

  const timesheetArray = from(
    this.cordovaFile
    .readAsArrayBuffer(this.cordovaFile.dataDirectory, storageId)
    .then((compressedTimesheet) => {
      const start = moment();
      const uint8array = new Uint8Array(compressedTimesheet);
      const jsonTimeSheet = this.LZString.decompressFromUint8Array(uint8array);
      this.log.debug(`LocalStorageMaterialService: getMaterials() from files: Decompression took ${moment().subtract(start.valueOf()).valueOf()} ms`);
      return <TimesheetModel[] > JSON.parse(jsonTimeSheet) || [];
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.log.debug('LocalStorageMaterialService: Retrieving materials from file storage was not possible: ', JSON.stringify(error));
      return [];
    })
  )
  timesheetArray.subscribe((timesheet) => {
    // here how to return an Array ??
  });
}
```

and just one example why i want to return an array but not observable

````
let matchedTimesheet = _.find<TimesheetModel>(this.getAllTimesheets() ,
(timesheet) => travelToDate 
&& timesheet.startOfWork.isSame(travelToDate.startDate.value, 'days')
            ); ```

here in the above code it is expecting an array but not Observable., I can do it by subscribing here also , but if the function returns an array instead of  observable, then i need to change everywhere
````

Comment: Why do you want to return an array instead an observable? How do you want to use your returned array?

Comment: You've created a service, ok, within your subscription save a copy of the timesheet to a variable that service clients can access. Your `getAllTimesheets()` effectively updates the service copy. Or better call next on a BehaviorSubject that clients can subscribe to.

Comment: @youri i have updated my question in better way, Please check

Comment: per Sidd's answer ```const subscription = getAllTimesheets().subscribe(timesheetData => {
    // Here you'll get that data.
    let matchedTimesheet = _.find<TimesheetModel>(timesheetData, timesheet) => travelToDate && timesheet.startOfWork.isSame(travelToDate.startDate.value, 'days'));
  })```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're thinking about this in the correct direction. `readAsArrayBuffer` is an asynchronous call. Hence it returns a promise.

You shouldn't simply return an `TimesheetModel[]` from your `getAllTimesheets()` method.

Rather, you should return an `Observable<TimesheetModel[]>`. But you'll have to make a small change wherever you're calling this `getAllTimesheets()` method.

Since it returns an `Observable<TimesheetModel[]>`, you'll have to either `subscribe` to `getAllTimesheets()` at all those places. Or you'll have to read this `Observable` in your template using the `async` pipe.

I'd recommend the latter.

So make this following changes to your `getAllTimesheets()` method.

```
public getAllTimesheets(): Observable<TimesheetModel[]> {
  const storageId = TIMESHEET_KEYS.ALL_TIMESHEET;
  return from(
    this.cordovaFile
    .readAsArrayBuffer(this.cordovaFile.dataDirectory, storageId)
    .then((compressedTimesheet) => {
      const start = moment();
      const uint8array = new Uint8Array(compressedTimesheet);
      const jsonTimeSheet = this.LZString.decompressFromUint8Array(uint8array);
      this.log.debug(`LocalStorageMaterialService: getMaterials() from files: Decompression took ${moment().subtract(start.valueOf()).valueOf()} ms`);
      return <TimesheetModel[] > JSON.parse(jsonTimeSheet) || [];
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.log.debug('LocalStorageMaterialService: Retrieving materials from file storage was not possible: ', JSON.stringify(error));
      return [];
    })
  );
}
```

And then wherever you're using it, if you're `subscribe`ing to it:

```
// unsubscribe this subscription on ngOnDestroy()
const subscription = getAllTimesheets()
  .subscribe(timesheetData => {
    // Here you'll get that data.
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't register your entire promise as an observable. Setup a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) and update the subject with the result of your promise using `.next()`. You can then subscribe to that result.

Assuming this is all in a service, you can set this up as follows:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TimesheetsService {
  /**
   * Create a new behavior subject with an empty array. This is what you will
   * subscribe to from outside of your service.
   */
  public timesheets$: BehaviorSubject<TimesheetModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor() {
    // Call your service method to GET your data.
    this.getAllTimesheets();
  }

  /**
   * This method is how you will update your behavior subject and can be called
   * from outside the service each time you want to update your result.
   */
  public getAllTimesheets() {
    return this.cordovaFile
      .readAsArrayBuffer(this.cordovaFile.dataDirectory, storageId)
      .then((compressedTimesheet) => {
        const uint8array = new Uint8Array(compressedTimesheet);
        const jsonTimeSheet = this.LZString.decompressFromUint8Array(uint8array);
        // On success, update the behavior subject with the result of your call.
        return timesheets$.next(JSON.parse(jsonTimeSheet));
      })
      // Or on error, update the behavior subject.
      .catch(() => timesheets$.next([]));
  }
}
```

Then in your component you can subscribe to your `result$` observable.

```js
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  timesheets: TimesheetModel[];

  constructor(private timesheetsService: TimesheetsService) {
    // Optionally call your service method again to GET fresh data.
    this.timesheetsService.getAllTimesheets();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * Subscribe to the result of your service call and pass the result to a
     * reference to be consumed by your component.
     */
    this.timesheetsService.timesheets$
      .subscribe((timesheets) => this.timesheets = timesheets);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the code again, i have edited it just now, I know that it will execute only after subscribing but how do i return array ?

Comment: I have updated my post now that I better understand what you're looking for. BehaviorSubject is the way to go.

Comment: Let me try , give me some 15 mins

Comment: you are telling me not to use this  ? `public getAllTimesheets(): TimesheetModel[] { ..}`

Comment: as i can see in your code, it is still not returning anything and `const timesheetArray ` is un used

Comment: @VikasKalapur - I have updated the code as a service to better explain the architecture within an angular application.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `as []`

```
timesheetArray.subscribe((timesheet) => {
    const time_sheet = timesheet as [];
});
```